# Using data from other funtions

Tags: python, function, scope, nameerror, hexdump

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. The main function works fine, but appending/writing the data into the .txt file function is not working. I keep getting "NameError: name 'data' is not defined". I'm guessing it's a scope problem?

Question: How do I run the main function and then write the output to a file? How can I access the output of the main function so I can run other functions on it?

Please help and Thank you!!

```
import sys, os

print("\n-------------------------- String HexDump ------------------------------------\n")


def main():
    try:
        with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as file:
            for line in range(0, os.path.getsize(sys.argv[1]), 60):
                data = file.read(60)
                data = str(data)
                print(data)
    except:
        print('Usage: {} <filename>'.format(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])))


str = lambda data: ''.join(31 < i < 127 and chr(i) or '.' for i in data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



def HexStrFileDump():
    with open('HEXDUMPFILE2.txt','wb') as HexFile:
        HexFile.write(data)

HexStrFileDump()
```

Comment: `data` should be global to the module. Now `data` is a local variable in your `main` function. Use the `global` keyword in the start of the function to import the global variable into the functions.

Comment: You can READ global variables without importing them with `global`, but not when assigning values to then.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Comment: You should return "data" from main() and pass that to HexStrFileDump() .

Comment: Using global variable is a bad option.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling all the functions in the incorrect order and with variables that do not exist (`data`) and out of scope.

If you use `main()` then concentrate all your code here and in subfunctions, best practice is to not spread around.

Your error comes from the improper use of `HexFile.write(data)` : data is the name of your lambda, not where your results are.

Here is a proper file hexdumper I wrote in 5 minutes for this answer:

```
import sys

def main():
    print("\n-------------------------- String HexDump ------------------------------------\n")
    try:
        with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as file:
            i = 0; clear = ""
            for char in file.read():
                if char > 0x19 and char < 0x7f:
                    clear = clear + chr(char)
                else:
                    clear = clear + "?"
                if i % 4 == 0 and i != 0:
                    clear = clear + " "
                    sys.stdout.write(" ")
                if i % 16 == 0 and i != 0:
                    sys.stdout.write(clear+"\n")
                    clear = ""
                    i = 0
                sys.stdout.write("%02X" % char)
                i += 1
            if i % 16 != 0:
                sys.stdout.write(" "+clear+"\n")
    except:
        raise
        print('Usage: {} <filename>'.format(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: IMO this doesn't do much to explain why the asker is seeing the error they're getting.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I tried to be more specific on the improper use of data in his code.

Answer (score 0):

You really should have posted the stack trace so we could see where the error is coming from, but you're lucky in that there is exactly one place in this program that can cause the error you're describing.

```
def HexStrFileDump():
    with open('HEXDUMPFILE2.txt','wb') as HexFile:
        HexFile.write(data)
                      ^
```

At that point in the code, the variable `data` is not defined. It would have to have some value assigned to it either earlier in the function, or at the module level, but you have not done that.

You have a `data` variable in `main()`, but that variable only exists inside `main()`, and you also have a different `data` variable inside the lambda function which you call `str`, but again, that variable only exists inside that function. As far as the code in `HexStrFileDump()` is concerned, those other `data` variables do not exist, which is why it's complaining about `data` not being defined.

Comment: Ok, so here is where I am at. I added "global data" and "return data" in my main function. Now when I run it, it does write to the file, however, it only writes the first line of data. I haven't been able to write everything to the file. To me, it seems I now have access to the data from the global variable added, or am I still wrong? Forgive me I am still learning.  @David Z